# How to handle thousands of request in REST based web service at a time?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous

Is making REST based web service (POST) asynchronous is the best way to handle thousands of requests at one time (Keeping in mind that I have only single instance of server serving the request)?

Edited:
Jersey is wrongly tagged.
For eg: I have a rest based web service, which is supposed to be consumed by 100 thousand clients within a very short span of time (~60 seconds). I understand that if I am allowed to deploy multiple instance of the server, then I can use a load balancer to handle all my incoming request and delegate them accordingly. But I am restricted to use only single instance. What design could I opt within this restriction? 
I could think of making the request asynchronous( which will not respond to client immediately ) in order to be able to let the server be free from this load and handle the requests at it's own pace. 
For now we can ignore memory limitations.
Please let me know if this clarifies your doubt?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? If a rest request is made Asynchronous by server then how will it ever return the value to client? By Asynchronous you mean an NIO based approach for your servers to scale up, then it has nothing to do with Jersey. Then again, even this has a limitation. And AFAIK Thousands of request per at once (exactly same time) might not be possible even with this approach.

Comment: You need to be more elaborate about the question. The answer would depend on the data storage of your choice. To help yourself: take a look into an advanced key-value storing service such Redis (https://redis.io/commands/incr) and read their documentation about rate limiting for your API. Other options are `nginx` - it is fast, and easy to configure by making  changes in the configuration file.

Comment: @AtlasShrugged  Hi.. thank you for your comments. I have edited the question with more explanation. Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: @chandresh.v Sorry but need more info even on your edited question. To scale upto what your asking, it mainly depends on what does your server do. As per AtlasShrugged suggestion, using redis (usually installed on a different server in prod, so might not help) or nginx is useful only for a distributed system. Since you mentioned you need a single instance, this might not give you any advantage. If your server needs to just respond with a static content then try considering `chronicle Map`. Its a key-value store like redis. again it depends on what your server does, so we can address that part.

Answer (score 2):

The term asynchronous could have different meanings in different places. For a web application code, it could refer to a Nonblocking I/O server such as Node or Netty/Akka which is a way for HTTP Requests to time multiplex on the same worker threads. If you're writing callbacks or using async or future constructs, it probably is non-blocking I/O which people sometimes refer to as asynchronous.

However, I could have REST API running on Node which implements non-blocking I/O, but the API or the overall architecture is still fully synchronous. For example, let's say I have an API endpoint POST /photos, which takes in a photo, creates image thumbnails, stores the URLs of the photo in a SQL Db and then stores the images in S3. The REST API could still block from the initial POST until after the image is processed and stored.

A second way is for the server to accept the photo process as a job and return immediately. Then the server could store the photo in a in memory or network based queue to be processed later by some other worker thread. In fact, I could even implement this async architecture even with a blocking server like some good old Java 7 and Jetty.